# Convert date and time to Iso 8601 in Kotlin

Tags: android, date, time, iso

I have a picker in my app that I can select the Year, Month, Day, Hour, and minute.
After changing each of them I have some numbers like this:

```
2022 -> for year
3 -> for month
20 -> for day
16 -> hour
58 -> minute
```

How can I convert these values to Iso 8601 date format?

I need like this format: "2022-03-20T16:58:00.288Z"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
val date = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
    set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
    set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
    set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day)
    set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
    set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
}.time 
val formattedDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'").format(date)
```

Answer (score 8):

Never use `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `TimeZone`, or the other legacy date-time classes.

Use `OffsetDateTime` of *java.time* classes

```
val localDate = LocalDateTime.of(2022, 1, 3, 16, 36)
//LocalDateTime of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute) 
val offsetDate = OffsetDateTime.of(localDate, ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

`ZoneOffset.UTC` - impleis that current time is of UTC time zone (LocalDate doesn't have any timezone information), can change to system default (`OffsetDateTime.now().offset`) or custom Zone offset (`ZoneOffset.of("+02:00")`)

**Convert to ISO Format**

```
val stringDate = offsetDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
Log.d("stringDate", "Date  $stringDate")
```

**Output :** 2022-01-03T11:36:00Z

**Note:** java.time classes or Java8 only works in Android 8 and above, to use these classes for lower version you need to enable desugaring - [Enable Desugaring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70448390/call-requires-api-level-24-java-util-comparator/70448747#70448747)