# How to parse date format in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello Stackoverflow team,
I am getting date and time from backend in this format **2022-03-12T18:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]**
Any idea how can we parse this.

I tried this :

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZZ[V]");

but getting an error:

```
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'V'**
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.time` classes to format the data

```
   val date = "2022-03-12T18:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]"
   //above data is standard ISO Format
   val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME
   val dateTime: ZonedDateTime= ZonedDateTime.parse(date, formatter)
   // format to any date format you require
   val formatter2: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM yyyy")
   Log.e("Date Format ", dateTime.format(formatter2))
```

Output:

```
E/Date Format: 12 Mar 2022
```

All predefined Format can be found here - [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)
**Note**: java.time classes or Java8 only works in Android 8 and above, to use these classes for lower version you need to enable desugaring - [Enable Desugaring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70448390/call-requires-api-level-24-java-util-comparator/70448747#70448747)

Comment: Hi @Nitish i am supporting from 21 and i think DateTimeFormattor will support from 26

Comment: You can enable desugaring for that, I mentioned that in my answer, it will allow support for java8 classes for api  level below 26

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using https://www.joda.org/joda-time/.
It's super useful and super straight forward.