# How to find all the errors

Tags: android, android-min-sdk

I have an Android app and I'm trying to make it working on an older device.

I decreased the **minSdk** in the build.gradle file and it compiles fine but when I run it, it crashes because of `Call requires API level 24 (current min is 22): java.util.List#sort`.

I tried to add `@RequiresApi(N) annotation` hoping to be able to detect all these errors at compile time but it is not.

Is there a smart solution to quickly find out all them?

Comment: Maybe this thread will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70448390/call-requires-api-level-24-java-util-comparator

Comment: To simply discover at compile-time all of your API-sensitive code, then temporarily set minSdk, targetSdk and compileSdk to same number (22 in this case) and rebuild.  Then address each error as needed.